# How to get data value from edit mask

Tags: powerbuilder

I have problem to get data value in editmask value(maskdatatype string)

I have already tried

```
em_sandi.getdata(sandi)
sandi = em_sandi.mask
```

and that not work

```
em_sandi.getdata(code)
DECLARE ret_acc CURSOR FOR
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table 
WHERE field1 = :code;
```

I want to get data value for the WHERE clause in my program

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, objectname.GetData(namealias)